# Understanding how to draw phase portraits/diagrams

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, dynamical-systems

In the book the author says that drawing phase portraits for dynamical systems and in particular for the periodic points helps visualize the dynamics of a system. However, I do not understand them nor do I know how to draw them. For example in the figure below in (a), the phase portrait is supposed to illustrate that every non-zero point is of period 2. I don't know how to see this from the picture. I can calculate and check such points by computations but I do not understand these diagrams and how to draw them.

Does anyone know how to understand them, construct them. And in particular what do the diagrams b, c, and d mean?

[image]

Edit: The figure is taken from Robert Devaney An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems, 2ed, 2003 p. 20. I also quote what the author has to say about it: "There is a much more efficient, geometric method for describing the orbits of a dynamical system, the phase portrait.
This is a picture, on the real line itself, as opposed to the plane, of all orbits of a system. For example, to indicate that all non-zero orbits of $f(x) =−x$ have period $2$, we could sketch the phase portrait as in Fig. $3.1.a$."; p. 20.

Comment: It's simple: From each point $x$, draw an arrow to the point $f(x)$. (Of course you can only *really* draw it for a finite subset of points, put in principle that's what it is.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Ok but how does that then illustrate the periodic points? Let's say for the diagram a. it is about the period $2$ points of $f(x) = -x$. So these would be $f^{2}(x) = f(f(x)) = f(-x) = x$ i.e. all points are period two points. But then if the phase portrait should illustrate these points, then we would have to draw an arrow from $x = 1$ to $f^{2}(1) = 1$ wouldn't we? I can't see how a. illustrates the periodic 2 points.

Comment: There's an arrow from $1$ to $-1$, and another arrow back from $-1$ to $1$. But in diagram (a) that's drawn with "double" arrows to save space. If you draw an arrow from $1$ back to $1$, you're drawing the phase portrait for $f^2$, not for $f$.

Comment: So we calculated that all $x$ are period two points of $f$ and then we substitute these points into $f$. Ok that makes sense for diagram $(a)$. If I do this for diagram $(d)$, i.e. for $f(x) = x^{3}$, then my fixed points will be $0, 1, -1$ and the same is true for period two points i.e. if we solve $f(f(x)) = x^{9} = x$ we get the same result. How are these now illustrated in diagram $(d)$? Now, we would have $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$, and $f(-1) = -1$.

Comment: Because now it seems that diagram (d) only does the orbit i.e. the iteration (composition) of $f$ with itself and just substitutes points into $f$. The first six arrows seem to be then points $-1 < x < 1$. But these diagrams are supposed to illustrate fixed points and periodic points not just applying the map to itself for each point.